# Discrete Random Variable - Probability of Sucessful Sales Call

Tags: statistics

I have this question in a mock exam:

A salesman makes 10 calls per hour. On each call, he completes a sale with probability 0.08. What is the probability he makes 2 or more successful calls in 1 hour?

I don't know how to answer this, I thought I could use X~Bin(10,0.8) and calculate the probability based on 1 - (Pr(x=0) + Pr(x=1)) but this doesn't work... How should I answer this?

Comment: Is the probability $0.08$ or $0.8$? You've written both of them. This is indeed a binomial random variable, so your idea should give the correct answer as long as you use the correct probability.

Comment: That was actually my issue. I for some reason kept using 0.8 instead of 0.08.